# KeyDown Commands dont want to fire.

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

So, i have two AutocompleteBoxes - i want to fire something when user press F3 or F5.

Xaml(i`m showing 2 ways i tried on purpose):

```
<my:AutoCompleteTextBox Name="cbStreet"
                                                DataContext="{Binding}"
                                                Provider="{Binding}"
                                                Text="{Binding Path=street,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                Style="{StaticResource ACStyle}">
                            <my:AutoCompleteTextBox.LoadingContent>
                                <TextBlock Text="Loading..."
                                           Margin="5"
                                           FontSize="14" />
                            </my:AutoCompleteTextBox.LoadingContent>
                            <my:AutoCompleteTextBox.InputBindings>
                                <KeyBinding Key="F3" Command="{Binding Path=StreetF3Command}"/>
                            </my:AutoCompleteTextBox.InputBindings>
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=StreetLostFocusCommand}" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="OnKeyDown" >
                                    <Command:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding Path=StreetF5Command}" 
                                     PassEventArgsToCommand="False"  
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding Path=city}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </my:AutoCompleteTextBox>
```

And ViewModel with 2 commands.

```
(...) 
 public ICommand StreetF3Command { get; set; }
 public ICommand StreetF5Command { get; set; }
(...) 
StreetF3Command = new CustomCommand(StreetF3, CanStreetF3);
StreetF5Command = new CustomCommand(StreetF5, CanStreetF5);
(...) 
private bool CanStreetF5(object obj)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void StreetF5(object obj)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<int>(3);
        }

        private bool CanStreetF3(object obj)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void StreetF3(object obj)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<int>(2);
        }
(...)
```

Thing is - when i hit F3 or F5 nothing happens. I tried to debugg it but application does not even hit in **StreetF5**
Funny thing is, LostFocus event works, and on other AutoCompleteTextBox very similar event works just fine.

Xaml:

```
<my:AutoCompleteTextBox Name="cbCity"
                                                Provider="{Binding Path=suggestionProviderCity}"
                                                Style="{StaticResource  ACStyle}"
                                                Text="{Binding Path=city,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                >
                            <my:AutoCompleteTextBox.LoadingContent>
                                <TextBlock Text="Loading..."
                                           Margin="5"
                                           FontSize="14" />
                            </my:AutoCompleteTextBox.LoadingContent>
                            <my:AutoCompleteTextBox.InputBindings>
                                <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding Path=CityF5Command}"/>
                            </my:AutoCompleteTextBox.InputBindings>
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=CityLostFocusCommand}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </my:AutoCompleteTextBox>
```

And ViewModel:

```
  public ICommand CityF5Command { get; set; }
    CityF5Command = new CustomCommand(CityF5, CanCityF5);
    private void CityF5(object obj)
            {
                Messenger.Default.Send<int>(1);
            }
```

I`m out of ideas.

Comment: I'm willing to bet all of the money in my pocket right now that this is a binding issue. Check your Output Window for clues.

Comment: Maybe it's a binding issue, maybe not, I had some similar problems in my application and in the end we decided to use the letter Keys instead of the function Keys. Regarding the Binding problems I had some issues with binding when the Datacontext was set on  the user control and said control used in a window in a different assembly and resolved it binding the model on the Grid (in my case) inside the UserControl containing all the UI parts instead of binding on the UserControl as a Whole. Doing it differently nothing worked as expected.

Comment: Have you tried the `PreviewKeyDown` event instead?

Comment: dyamond I did.

@MikeEason Thanks a lot, binding was a problem. I missed a moment when i changed datacontext of AutoCompletetextbox. Thanks a lot mon

I trully need to think about changing this ACTB on something more friendly.

Comment: No problem, always check the Output Window for clues. Happy investigating!